# Force directed graph stops being responsive

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

```
var containerdiv = document.getElementById("container");
var svg = d3.select(containerdiv).append("svg")

// Extract the width and height that was computed by CSS.
var width = containerdiv.clientWidth;
var height = containerdiv.clientHeight;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2));

function redraw(){

  console.log("window is being redrawn");

  width = containerdiv.clientWidth;
  height = containerdiv.clientHeight;

  simulation.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2));

  // Use the extracted size to set the size of an SVG element.
  svg
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

}

// Redraw based on the new size whenever the browser window is resized.
window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);
```

Currently I am trying to get a responsive window using this code above. The `forceSimulation` changes its center a couple of times, before it stops becoming responsive to window resizing. I have the statement: `console.log("window is being redrawn");` and I know that `CSS` detects every time I resize the window. But the behavior is as follows:

### Initial call to function `redraw`

[image]

---

### Window resizing works

[image]

---

### Window resizing has stopped working

[image]

Comment: try to use a listenner: `window.addEventListener("resize", redraw);`
with a complete reinit of your d3. gl

Comment: @pirs I forgot to add that line. What do you mean by: "with a complete reinit of your d3. gl"

Comment: You should put almost all your d3 code in the redraw, it ll be more stable basically.

Comment: ^-- don't do that: it's unnecessary and it will reduce performance.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I agree, I tried that, and it reduced performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 simulations have an internal timer and only run a given amount of ticks (around 300) before cooling down.

Therefore, you'll have to reheat the simulation, using `restart()`. According to the API, `restart()`:

> Restarts the simulation’s internal timer and returns the simulation. In conjunction with simulation.alphaTarget or simulation.alpha, this method can be used to “reheat” the simulation during interaction, such as when dragging a node, or to resume the simulation after temporarily pausing it with simulation.stop.

So, you could do this in your `redraw` function:

```
simulation.alpha(.8).restart();
```